# How to make a shadow_mark without interpolating points?

Tags: r, gganimate

How can I create an animation that 1. adds new points to the plot at a time proportional to the measurement time, and 2. fades out older points over time?

I thought maybe I could achieve this with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
set.seed(1)

ex =
expand.grid(x = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
            y = seq(0, 1, 0.2),
            t = seq(0, 10, 1)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(z = rnorm(x, mean = t, sd = 0.2))

ggplot(data = ex,
       mapping = aes(x, y, color = z)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.02, height = 0.02)) +
  transition_time(t) +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  shadow_mark(alpha = 0.4, size = 1)
```

[image: generated animation]

However, this plot interpolates the position of the point across time. While this makes sense to do for reproducing gapminder, it doesn't seem to be the effect I'm looking for: I want the same thing, but with no moving balls. I just want them to appear and then to fade out. But I'm wondering if there is a nice way to do this using the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watching Thomas's talk on [A Grammar of Visualization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21ZWDrTukEs) I saw in his ggraph example that, yes, he had my problem in mind when formulating the grammar.

```
ggplot(data = ex,
       mapping = aes(x, y, color = z)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.02, height = 0.02)) +
  transition_events(start = t, 
                    enter_length = 1,
                    exit_length = 4) +
  scale_color_viridis_c() +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()
```

[image: proposed solution]